# Windows 7: Opening Command Prompt with Shortcut Icon in Directory of Icon

Tags: windows-7, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, icons

I am trying to open the command prompt for the directory that the shortcut icon is currently located in. However, I want to be able to move this given icon to another directory (using my mouse to drag it into a new folder in the Windows Explorer) and be able to double click it to open the command prompt in that new directory.

I am wanting to use something along the lines of "cmd /k "cd cwd" & {other commands}" where cwd would give the current working directory that the icon is located in.

I am having issues because I cannot just use 'cmd-here' in the target line.

Any suggestions?

This is the current configuration I have.

[image]

Comment: Hold shift key while in any folder and right click, select "open command window here" from the context menu.

Comment: I am trying to create an icon that will automatically do this so that I can run specific commands in the command prompt (in the current working directory) simply by double clicking on an icon. Unless you know of a better way to approach this than using the shortcut icon, I think this is the route I have to take.

Comment: I see no easy way to do what you want, but someone smarter than me may have a solution. You need to edit your question and add this new information on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am wanting to use something along the lines of "cmd /k "cd cwd" & {other commands}" where cwd would give the current working directory that the icon is located in.

Comment: Please use the edit button and add this to your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Force a CMD shortcut to open in a directory the shortcut resides

Simply put [`%cd%`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) into the **`Start in:`** field and this will ensure the **cmd.exe** opens in whatever folder the shortcut resides at the time of execution—I've tested this and confirmed it to work just as described (and requested) on both **Windows 7** and **Windows 10**.

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

  > Display the current drive and directory:
  >
  > ```
  > C:\Work> ECHO "%CD%"
  > ```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. As a side note, I had to create a completely new shortcut because editing the previous one would just produce the previous result I was running into—any ideas why that would occur?

Comment: No problem, I've seen bad shortcuts cause funny problem before like you explain but I never troubleshot much to figure out what caused as the solution was more timely but I too have experienced this but cannot say what the cause to that is but I suspect it's something to do with the properties of it somewhere.