# Run a batch file when folder is opened with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, hotkeys

I have been wanting to run a custom batch file, when a folder is opened with a hotkey from File Explorer

**Question:**

- Can you run a custom action in File Explorer, when opening a folder with hotkeys?

Comment: e.g. Opening a code-project dir, while holding 'Ctrl' also opens Cygwin there too

Comment: Why not just have the batch file hot key open the specific folder you need (e.g. `explorer.exe c:\projects\project-4-shizzle`)? Then you can put additional logic in it to do something like open the folder and then take further action

Comment: perhaps having a hotkey combo then act on the selected folder? I want to use this across multiple projects, for git access via Cygwin

Comment: Maybe drop a batch in each folder and have a hotkey to press it then, or perhaps the shortcut key combos to execute that batch from Windows File Explorer. The batch logic could use `%cd%` for the current folder variable them like `echo %cd%` to get current path the batch reside to be more dynamic.

Comment: Using something similar to the method here: https://superuser.com/questions/1312668/windows-7-opening-command-prompt-with-shortcut-icon-in-directory-of-icon/1312681#1312681 but passing the execution of the logic to run with cmd.exe may make it better. Just some quick thoughts based on your words only and not with 100% certainty, for ideas and if nothing else.

Comment: you guys, rock - be right back 